# Background processing for jailbroken iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I want to make an app in which there would be a background process which changes ringtone every few hours. The background process also needs to be able to make connection to the web server to download ringtones if available.

I want to make this app for jailbroken devices only so appstore submission is not a problem. I'm really not sure if we can have such background processing capability. Any ideas?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Developing for jailbroken devices is not easy, there isn't a lot of documentation available and you'll have to figure out a LOT of things on your own. Take your question as a first exercise, if you can't figure it on your own, you are probably not ready to do the project you are planning to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have background processes on a jailbroken iPhone.  I'm not sure if you have any UI or not.  Perhaps you'll build a normal **app** UI for occasional interactions with the user, and a background **daemon** that periodically checks the server for new ringtones, and resets the phone's ringtone.

Look at [this tutorial for how to build an iPhone daemon process](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/?p=7).